# Sonarqube-8.0 Wrapper Stoped when Starting

Tags: java, c#, asp.net-core, web, sonarqube

i downloaded sonarqube 8.0 version and installed java 13.x.x. but when i run StartSonar.bat command in administrator cmd. it stoped wrapper. can anyone give me a solution to run sonarqube locally?

this is cmd out put

```
D:\sonarqube-8.0\sonarqube-8.0\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2019.12.10 12:37:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\sonarqube-8.0\sonarqube-8.0\temp
jvm 1    | 2019.12.10 12:37:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2019.12.10 12:37:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [D:\sonarqube-8.0\sonarqube-8.0\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-8.0\sonarqube-8.0\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=D:\sonarqube-8.0\sonarqube-8.0\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=D:\sonarqube-8.0\sonarqube-8.0\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2019.12.10 12:37:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
jvm 1    | 2019.12.10 12:37:24 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2019.12.10 12:37:24 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2019.12.10 12:37:31 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2019.12.10 12:37:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.12.10 12:37:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i sorted out this issue. it was happen due to compatible jdk version.now i using java 11.0.5. it runs smoothly with my sonarQube 8.0